# Parsing mean temperature from weather web site HTML

Tags: regex, vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Hi I want to use VBA to pull data from weather web site. What I'm trying to do is to get number 6 from this HTML code:

```
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="indent"><span>Temperatura średnia</span></td>
                <td>
          <span class="wx-data"><span class="wx-value">6</span><span class="wx-unit">&nbsp;&#176; C</span></span>
    </td>
            <td>
      -
    </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="indent"><span>Temperatura maksymalna</span></td>
        <td>
  <span class="wx-data"><span class="wx-value">7</span><span class="wx-unit">&nbsp;&#176; C</span></span>
</td>
        <td>
  <span class="wx-data"><span class="wx-value">8</span><span class="wx-unit">&nbsp;&#176; C</span></span>
</td>
```

I tried code like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim IE As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False

    ' URL to get data from
    IE.Navigate "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EPGD/2016/10/24/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Pruszcz%20Gdanski&req_statename=Polska&reqdb.zip=00000&reqdb.magic=86&reqdb.wmo=12140"

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."

    Dim dd As String
    dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("Temperatura średnia")(0).innerText

    MsgBox dd

    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Without any result (the code does nothing). I will appreciate any help.

Comment: "Temperatura średnia" does not appear to be the class name "wx-value" is.  what happens when you try `dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("wx-value")(0).innerText`  ?  if this page has other wx-values, then you'd need to loop through them.

Comment: Can you expand on "the code does nothing"? Does the status bar ever get set to "Loading, please wait..."? How about the searching message? Does the document ever get loaded? Could you MsgBox the html from one of the elements to check that it does? Can you find the element you're looking for?

Comment: I edited HTML code in op with more lines. The wx-value repeats :(

Comment: status bar get set to loading but it shows error on line                              dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("Temperatura średnia")(0).innerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example using XHR and RegEx to retrieve all table data from the webpage:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDataWunderground()

    Dim aResult() As String
    Dim sContent As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    ' retrieve html content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EPGD/2016/10/24/DailyHistory.html", False
        .Send
        sContent = .ResponseText
    End With
    ' parse with regex
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        ' minor html simplification
        .Pattern = "<span[^>]*>|</span>|[\r\n\t]*"
        sContent = .Replace(sContent, "")
        ' match each table row
        .Pattern = "<tr><td class=""indent"">(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td></tr>"
        With .Execute(sContent)
            ReDim aResult(1 To .Count, 1 To 4)
            ' each row
            For i = 1 To .Count
                With .Item(i - 1)
                    ' each cell
                    For j = 1 To 4
                        aResult(i, j) = DecodeHTMLEntities(.SubMatches(j - 1))
                    Next
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End With
    ' output result
    Cells.Delete
    Output Cells(1, 1), aResult
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Function DecodeHTMLEntities(sText As String) As String

    Static oHtmlfile As Object
    Static oDiv As Object

    If oHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set oHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        oHtmlfile.Open
        Set oDiv = oHtmlfile.createElement("div")
    End If
    oDiv.innerHTML = sText
    DecodeHTMLEntities = oDiv.innerText

End Function

Sub Output(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)
    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
            UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
            UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1 _
        )
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The output is as follows for me:

[image: output]

To extract the mean temperature only you can get the value from the first match having 0 index, since the mean temperature is in the first row of the table:

```
Sub ExtractMeanTempWunderground()

    Dim sContent As String

    ' retrieve html content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EPGD/2016/10/24/DailyHistory.html", False
        .Send
        sContent = .ResponseText
    End With
    ' parse with regex
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        ' minor html simplification
        .Pattern = "<span[^>]*>|</span>|[\r\n\t]*"
        sContent = .Replace(sContent, "")
        ' match each table row
        .Pattern = "<tr><td class=""indent"">.*?</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>.*?</td><td>.*?</td></tr>"
        With .Execute(sContent)
            If .Count = 15 Then
                ' get the first row value only
                MsgBox DecodeHTMLEntities(.Item(0).SubMatches(0))
            Else
                MsgBox "Data structure inconsistence detected"
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function DecodeHTMLEntities(sText As String) As String

    Static oHtmlfile As Object
    Static oDiv As Object

    If oHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set oHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        oHtmlfile.Open
        Set oDiv = oHtmlfile.createElement("div")
    End If
    oDiv.innerHTML = sText
    DecodeHTMLEntities = oDiv.innerText

End Function
```

Note, such methods will work until the webpage structure is changed.

Comment: Hi this works grat. Is there way to retrieve only "Mean Temperature" value without unnecessary data?

Comment: Thank you ! I have no idea how you made this code to work with such awesome perofrmance :D

Comment: @eurano XHR usually shows better performance than IE automation. If this answer solves the issue, please click to accept it.