# Search for the character & rather than the converted &amp; in mailItem.HTMLBody

Tags: vba, character-encoding, outlook

I have a function which finds a string between to given strings. Here is an example:

```
midReturn("?sender=", "&to=", mailItem.HTMLBody)
```

The above should get the string between `?sender` and `&to` but the `&` is converted to `&amp;`.

Is there a way i can look for both occurrences? I did a statement to check this but it doesn't work:

```
Dim from = midReturn("?sender=", "&amp;to=", mailItem.HTMLBody)

If from < 1 Then
    from = midReturn("?sender=", "&to=", mailItem.HTMLBody)
End If
```

Comment: HTML body is going to be HTML-encoded, so `&` will be `&amp;` - that's what HTML-encoding does. What `midReturn` does is rather unclear though. Also `Dim foo = bar` is illegal in VBA. If this is VB.NET code, then the declare-and-assign syntax is valid, and you can easily HTML-decode the `HTMLBody` using the appropriate imports. If this is VBA code, you need to decode the HTML yourself AFAIK, or use a library that can do it.

Comment: Can you post the code for midReturn? I'm sure the answer is pretty simple.

Comment: Try to decode HTML entities using `Function DecodeHTMLEntities()` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40410204/2165759), then parse the string.